# R bioconductor GO terms output interpretation

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to get the ancestor go term from a list of go terms. I used bioconductor in R for this task. But I'm quite confused about the result. I will give some examples of results: 
**input:**

```
AT3G52150   GO:0009570  GO:0009941  GO:0009570  GO:0009535  GO:0009579  GO:0009941  GO:0009507  GO:0009570  GO:0009570  GO:0009570  GO:0009570  GO:0009570  GO:0009579  GO:0009507  GO:0009507  GO:0009570  GO:0009579  GO:0009535  GO:0009579  GO:0009570  GO:0009570  GO:0009507  GO:0009507  GO:0009941  GO:0009941  GO:0009507  GO:0009570  GO:0009570  GO:0009535  GO:0009535  GO:0009535  
AT1G56450   GO:0022626  GO:0022626  GO:0005839  GO:0005737  GO:0005829  GO:0022626  GO:0022626  GO:0005737  GO:0000502  GO:0005839  
AT3G07100   GO:0005789  GO:0030127  GO:0033116  GO:0000139  GO:0030127  GO:0005789  GO:0005789  GO:0000139  GO:0033116  GO:0033116  GO:0030127  GO:0005737  GO:0005789  GO:0000139  GO:0000139  
AT1G07040   GO:0009507
```

**output:**

```
[1] "GO:0005622" "GO:0005575" "GO:0005623" "GO:0044424" "GO:0044464" "all"       
[1] "GO:0005622" "GO:0005575" "GO:0005623" "GO:0044424" "GO:0044464" "all"       
[1] "GO:0005622" "GO:0005575" "GO:0005623" "GO:0044424" "GO:0044464" "all"       
[1] "GO:0005622" "GO:0005575" "GO:0005623" "GO:0005737" "GO:0043231" "GO:0009536" "GO:0043226"
[1] "GO:0043227" "GO:0043229" "GO:0044424" "GO:0044444" "GO:0044464" "all"
```

I will explain what this result means, so I combined the different cellular component of ONE accesion number and get the parent of these (using GOCCANCESTOR in R). So every line in the output I pasted above are the parents belonging to the cellular components of one accesionnumber.

However, I don't understand the output. I assume "all" is the top of the hierarchy of all cellular component GO terms (not sure about this because I wasn't able to find any documentation about it). 
So I thought further to the right means higher in the hierarchy, however if this is true it would be strange that on the left side all the go terms are te same, I would expect this on the right side if "all" means the top. 
I hope somone is familair with the GO terms or with GOCCANCESTOR in R 


**update**
In the case those terms aren't sorted, how can I sort them so I got the lowest possible in the hiarchy?

*I wasn't sure if I had to post this on stackoverflow or biology so if you think it shouldn't be posted here let me know*

Comment: It would help if you showed the term(s) for which you got this result. But generally it doesn’t seem that these are sorted either left-to-right or right-to left. For instance, both GO:0005623 and GO:0044464 are child terms of GO:0005575.

Comment: Thankyou I updated my question @KonradRudolph (the go terms are some others then I just showed in my question before the edit, because I couldn't find the input for that quickly)